# Can I enable login prompt for user for elevation prompt request instead of CRT ALT DEL?

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-10

I am trying to enable login credential pop up screen for elevation prompt requests instead of CRTL ALT DEL pop up in Windows 10.I was able to do this actually on my test machine but it doesnt work in work environment.I dont have much windows experience so I was thinking if anyone can help me ?

Note ; I am not referring disabling CRTL ALT DEL for Windows interactive log on.When you run cmd or change network settings as standard user , it will prompt CRTL ALT DEL and I want to disable it enable credential login so user can authenticate .

Comment: Hi, Your goal is what ? as by GPO you can bypass this prompt completly usually.

Comment: ctrl-alt-end should simulate ctrl-alt-delete in the second session... but I'm not understanding the question either.  Are you trying to disable UAC?  Are you trying to make it so that a regular user can do administrative functions?  I'm confused, but it might be a language barrier issue...

Comment: thanks for the quick answer Glenn Sullivan! I am not trying to disable UAC at all .All I want  to do enable UAC credential prompt but disabling  CRTL ALT DEL .I already enabled UAC credential prompt from local group policy settings however I couldnt find how to disable CRT ALT DEL prompt.Let me give you example ;Lets say I am a standard user logged on to windows 10 client machine and I want to run windows CMD as admin .normally this attempt will bring up CRTL ALT DEL prompt but instead of CRT ALT DEL , I want to bring login Credential prompt.  hopefully this helps better